# Show that $H_{2^n}$ $\leq$ $1+n$ with induction

Tags: induction, proof-explanation

Use mathematical induction to show that $H_{2^n}$ $\leq$ $1+n$, whenever n is a nonnegative integer.
PS: $H_{2^n}$ denotes the $2^n$th harmonic number.

Comment: Do you know the famous proof of the divergence of the harmonic series?

Comment: Yes. Thank you. I'm not that good with tex.

Comment: @nayrb No. I don't know...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the induction basis and the hypothesis of induction are easy steps you can do them. Now, if it is supposed that $H_{2^k}\le 1+k$ for some integer $k\ge 1$ we have
\begin{align*}
H_{2^{k+1}}&=H_{2^k}+\sum_{j=1}^{2^k}\frac{1}{2^k+j}\\[5pt]
&\le 1+k+\sum_{j=1}^{2^k}\frac{1}{2^k}\\[5pt]
&= 1+(k+1)
\end{align*}

Comment: I don't understand the second and the third step. Why the sum of 1/(2^k + j) from j = 1 to 2^k is bigger than k + the sum 1/(2^k) from j = 1 to 2^k? Why the sum of 1/2^k from j = 1 to 2^k is equal to 1?